# LogicException in CryptKey.php line 44

Tags: php, laravel, postman

> LogicException in CryptKey.php line 44: Key path
>   "file:///home/brulltaxiapp/public_html/storage/oauth-public.key" does
>   not exist or is not readable

i am getting this exception when i call api in postman

headers i am sending is

```
[{"key":"Accept","value":"application/json","description":"","enabled":true,"warning":""}]
```

i have installed laravel in `public_html` means all files and folders which are normally in public folder are in `public_html`

i think its path issue i have installed laravel using root user

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: yes i solved it .it was because of php.ini was not placed in proper location.i placed it in root and it solved the problem